# Does it make sense to talk about limit in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose I have a function that is defined only for values bigger than $a$, does it make sense to talk about limit of a function at that point, or only about limit from the right? It seems to me that we can talk about limit of a function, because if we look at the definition
$$\forall \epsilon>0 \; \exists \delta>0 \; \forall x\in A: \; 0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
($A$ is domain of the function), we have the requirement of $x$ being in the domain and so limit still would make sense. But I am not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. In such a case, the concepts of **limit** and **right-hand limit** coincide.

For example, it doesn't make any difference whether you write
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x} = 0
$$
or
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sqrt{x} = 0
.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If a function is not defined for values smaller than or equal to $a$, then you can't deal with anything in that range of values. As such, for limits, you can certainly talk about a limit from the right. A general "limit" would either be considered to not exist, but I believe it would usually mean determining it only from the right, as mentioned. This might depend, to some extent, on the specific context in which the limit is being asked about. I hope this answers what you're specifically asking about.